# RazorEngine and parsing physical view files always causes exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following RazorEngine call:

```
public class RazorEngineRender
{
    public static string RenderPartialViewToString(string templatePath, string viewName, object model)
    {            
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(templatePath, viewName));
        string renderedText = Razor.Parse(text, model);
        return renderedText;
    }
}
```

This is called from:

```
_emailService.Render(TemplatePath, "Email.cshtml", new { ActivationLink = activationLink });
```

I also have this view file (email.cshtml):

```
    <div>
      <div>
            Link: <a href="@Model.ActivationLink" style="color:#666" target="_blank">@Model.ActivationLink</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When the call to Razor.Parse() occurs, I always get a:
Unable to compile template. Check the Errors list for details.

The error list is:

```
error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ActivationLink' and no extension method 'ActivationLink' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found
```

I've tried everything under the sun, including trying a concrete type as opposed to anonymous type, declaring the @Model line at the top of the view file but no luck.  I'm wondering if the library is at fault or definately me?

By the way, the razorengine I am referring to is available here at codeplex:
[RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Can you post your Render method? I'm one of the developers on the project and that method isn't in our library so there is something between the two that is causing the problem.

Comment: Oh, duh! It's already there...Just named differently in your sample. Hold on

Comment: I'd definitely look at using MVC Mailer (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MvcMailerNuGet.aspx) or Postal (http://aboutcode.net/postal/) before creating your own version.

Comment: Your method parameter is of type object is where your cast occurs. The Razor.Parse() call is generic, and through type inference its selecting the object type (the cast). You could make your method call generic, accepting a model type of T and pass it directly to the razor call.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you make the call like so:

```
Razor.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(YourPath), 
            new { ActivationLink = activationLink });
```

That should give you the correct output. But after I see your method posted above I'll be able to make a determination where the problem lies.

### Update

Change your method to the following:

```
public class RazorEngineRender {
    public static string RenderPartialViewToString<T>(string templatePath, string viewName, T model) {            
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(templatePath, viewName));
        string renderedText = Razor.Parse(text, model);
        return renderedText;
    }
}
```

and you can call it like you do above.

The reason it doesn't work is because you're telling the Parser that the model is of type object rather than passing in what type it really is. In this case an anonymous type.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help on this, greatly appreciated. I'm really lucky that your one of the devs on this! Yes I needed the Razor call with <T> like you said. And then in my view, I don't need the @model definition at the top. Just the @Model.[whatever] sufficed.

Comment: Yeah, the @model actually will fail in it's current state as the @model isn't supported yet. I've added support for it but it will only be used to add intellisense for editing of cshtml files - it might also be used to validate the model type passed it, but I'm not sure yet.

Glad it worked for you though!

Comment: RazorEngine is driving me nuts. I have the same issue as original question, but to make matters worse it seems to work once and then stop working after the app recompiles. Would somebody post a working sample with both the file template and the code to call it?

Comment: What is your error specifically @CDeutsch? is it with the razor engine or, like this question, with an html helper and not the engine itself? Create your own question with posted code and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: That would be awesome if you could take a look. I made a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756507/razorengine-unable-to-compile-template-error

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer was perfect in 2011 (I believe pre-v3 of RazorEngine) but this code is now marked as obsolete in latest version (in time of typing it is 3.7.3).

For newer version your method can be typed like this:

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString<T>(string templatePath, string templateName, string viewName, T model)
        {
            string template = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(templatePath, viewName));
            string renderedText = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, templateName, typeof(T), model);
            return renderedText;
        }
```

and in order for it to work you need to add

```
using RazorEngine.Templating;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few hints you might try:

1. Make your razor view strongly typed to a model:

   ```
   @model Foo
   <div>
       <div>
           Link: 
           <a href="@Model.ActivationLink" style="color:#666" target="_blank">
               @Model.ActivationLink
           </a>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. When rendering it pass a `Foo` model:

   ```
   _emailService.Render(
       TemplatePath, 
       "Email.cshtml", 
       new Foo { ActivationLink = activationLink }
   )
   ```
3. If you are trying to send emails from your Views make sure you [checkout Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) before reinventing something.

Comment: Its the RazorEngine, I've added a link on my first post at the end of the post.  I think it is a wrapper round the MVC razor, so that it's possible to create templates in code or from files.  I've tried a strongly type model like above and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Jon, oops indeed, didn't notice.

Comment: It's not a wrapper around MVC Razor it uses the actual Razor parser - which is actually separate from MVC. MVC creates it's own wrapper around the Razor parser too.