# RazorEngine "Unable to compile template" Error

Tags: c#, .net, razor, razorengine

I'm using the following code to build and send an email using RazorEngine.

```
//build email using template.
string template = File.OpenText(EmailTemplatePath).ReadToEnd();
OrganizationInviteEmailTemplate model = new OrganizationInviteEmailTemplate()
{
    FirstName = Invitation.FirstName,
    LastName = Invitation.LastName,
    Message = Message,
    OrganizationName = Invitation.Organization.OrganizationName,
    ConfirmUrl = string.Format(ConfirmUrlTemplate, Invitation.InviteCode)
};
string body = Razor.Parse(template, model);

//email the invitation.
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add(Invitation.Email);
message.Subject = "Invitation From " + Invitation.Organization.OrganizationName;
message.Body = body;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

The template is below:

```
 <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
         <h3>@Model.OrganizationName has invited you to be part of their organization</h3>

         <p>
         Hi @Model.FirstName,
         </p>

         .....etc......
     </body>
 </html>
```

I get the "Unable to compile template" error 9 times out of 10 and then it will work once after I adjust the template by removing **Model.** and/or adjusting the code to use **Parse** instead, but then it will go right back to not working. It's like something is caching a piece of code briefly or something.

I'm using the RazorEngine.dll included with [RazorJS](http://john.katsiotis.com/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files), version 2.1.4113.149. Maybe that's the issue. Going to try [this library](http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/use-razor-for-email-template-outside-asp-dot-net-mvc) or [Postal](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal) next since this is taking way too much time already. Or just hard code the damn thing.

Comment: Take a look onto the RazorEngine discussions on codeplex: http://razorengine.codeplex.com/discussions/248593.

Comment: Just to clarify, is your template built correctly? meaning all html tags have closing tags when appropriate? the post here doesn't show the closing `<h3>` tag so that might be causing it to fail - nevermind someone edited your post weirdly

Comment: I created a quick `OrganizationInviteEmailTemplate` model, populated it and ran it with your snipped and it worked fine. Email me ben@ this name.com with a copy of your model and the full template and I'll be able to look and see where the error might be.

Comment: Well thanks for looking. It must have something to do with other assemblies or that it's executing in IIS. I don't think we're going to solve this, so just going to hard code it and use string.Format. I've spent way too much time already trying to get this to work.

Comment: No problemo. I can tell you this: I use the RazorEngine in a production web app on an IIS7 server as well as in a windows application here at my work. I've come across a few bugs but nothing that prevents it from working outright with a few tweaks to the templates.

Comment: Just an FYI, I removed RazorJS and the problem when away. My guess would be RazorJS is reconfiguring some globals and causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you want to code it all by yourself, it will be more easy to install a nuget package like [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide).

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you missing the @model declaration at the top of your template?